# Using my own Cell object in XCODE

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, cell

I have successfully created my on "cell" object (based on UITableViewCell) and have successfully used it while building a table via **cellForRowAtIndexPath**.

However, how do I deconstruct what I have done within **didSelectRowAtIndexPath**?

I currently receive the error **"Incompatible pointer types initializing 'MyCell *__strong' with an expression of type 'UITableViewCell'"**

Given my object (MyCell) is based on UITableViewCell I don't understand why I am getting this error.

Can you please help me understand what I am doing wrong.

My alternative is to use a "TAG" for each of the two labels in the cell and get them that way, but I am just experimenting here trying to learn more about how this all works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"myCellID";
    MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[MyCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

cell.accountCode.text = @"0009810";
cell.accountName.text = @"Agent Name";

return cell;
}
```

Here is the other method. I get the error on **MyCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// Get the cell that was selected
MyCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

AccountRecord *accountRecord = [[AccountRecord alloc] init];
accountRecord.accountCode = cell.accountCode.text;
accountRecord.accountName = cell.accountName.text;

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"AccountDetail" sender:accountRecord];

}
```

And here is MyCell

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UILabel *accountCode;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UILabel *accountName;

@end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change this:

```
MyCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

to the following:

```
MyCell *cell = (MyCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: Oh wow. That easy? So I guess this is basically "casting" the result to my object?

Comment: Yes, you need to cast it because you are using custom cell.

Comment: Excellent. That did the trick. Thank you so much for an almost instant reply to my post. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to cast the UITableViewCell* to MyCell*

```
MyCell *cell = (MyCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Everything else looks ok to me.

Typically I wouldn't get the cell information by calling cellForRowAtIndexPath, I would instead get it from the underlying data model.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Regarding your suggestion of using the underlying data model, I have seem MANY examples of using an array to hold all of the table data. I have up to a couple of thousand rows (with an easy search function to help the user find them). I was thinking that building an array with all the information as well as it being in the table is really doubling up on memory. Therefore I was looking at getting the information out of the table to segue to the next VC rather than looking at a data model. Should I not worry about memory and use the array method anyway?

Comment: You only have about as many cells as fit on the screen in existence anyway. They are recycled as they go offscreen and used to display the next elements coming onto the screen. You will always need some way to populate the data into the cell in the first place so you should be able to use that mechanism in didSelectRowAtIndexPath rather than getting the cell.